# How to check if user exists in database with axis.get to Api Gateway?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, axios, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to write that will check if the username exists in the database when I clicked login.

is there any way to write a function containing axios.get(URL).then() such that it will give me a boolean result? True if the username exists and false otherwise.

```
import axios from 'axios' 

function validateUser(username) {
   URL: API_GATEWAY_URL
   isExist = true;
   axios.get(url + '?username=' + username) 
   .then(response => {
     return response.json})
   .then(json => {
     if(json.data.statusCode != 200)
     { 
      isExist = false;
     }
    })
   .catch(error => console.error(error))

   return isExist;
}
```

However, isExist can't seem to be mutated regardless if (json.data.statusCode != 200) is true or not. Please help, i'm new to JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `axios.get` returns [`Promise`](https://javascript.info/promise-basics) which works asyncly. So your `isExist` not mutated. Also you should return promise from `validateUser` to whenever you need to control state.

Also you can use [`async/await`](https://javascript.info/async-await).

EDIT: (minimal implementation in some React/Pseudocode manner)

```
// api.js
import axios from 'axios' 

function validateUser(username) {
   return axios.get(url + '?username=' + username)
}
// main.js
import api from 'api'

onUserKeypress(username) {
    api.validateUser(username)
        .then(({json}) => {
            if(json.data.statusCode != 200) {
                this.form.valid = false;
                this.showError(username)};
         })
}
```

Comment: okay. So my aim is to check if the username typed on the login form already exists in the database which is accessible from the API Gateway. How do i create a function such that it will get the information from the database and then give a boolean if the username match with one found on the database? (statuscode == 200)

Comment: It depends on JS framework you are using (or not using at all). Also what you described also uses Promise. So you function cant just return value from promise because you should waiting and for this function.